# How do I define a function for an angular scope using '='?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS (1.5)
The component is defined as such (names changed due to company stuff):

```
angular.module('main').component('comp1', [
  bindings: {
    saveThing: '='
  }, ...
```

The component uses the saveThing function later down the line, but it is not defined within the component. I cannot change the code of the component (not my departments), how abouts do I pass in a function? Thanks!
Location of this component:

```
<parentDirective>
  <comp1></comp1>
</parentDirective>
```

The function I want to pass in is defined in parentDirective, and in the component, it is called by `$ctrl.saveThing` instead of `$scope.saveThing`. Thanks!

Comment: `<comp1 save-thing="$ctrl.save"></comp1>`

Comment: @dfsq I tried that, but it seems to not work - they're calling $ctrl.saveThing instead of $scope.saveThing (mb, I'll add that to the Q)

Comment: What is your $ctrl? Did you tried to debug your code and see what it is in your scope?

Comment: @Gabrielle, it is the controller function. Defined as such: `angular.module(..).component('comp1', [... controller: ['$scope',... function1] .... ;`
then later in function1: `var $ctrl = this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been solved. Depsite in the component:

```
bindings: {
  saveThing: '='
}
```

I realized in the directive, I must use `save-thing'"whateverFunc"` instead of `saveThing="whateverFunc"`.

Example:

```
<parentDirective>
   <comp1 save-thing="yay"></comp1>
</parentDirective>
```